# BitCovert in C# to Java and

Tags: java, c#

I make in C#.

```
byte[] counter_bytes = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? BitConverter.GetBytes(counter).Reverse().ToArray() : BitConverter.GetBytes(counter);
```

I do not know write to Java

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitconverter for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865728/bitconverter-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

[This class](https://github.com/peace-maker/lysis-java/blob/master/src/lysis/BitConverter.java) looks like it suites your needs, it doesn't appear to have a specific license though, so be careful and ask permission from the author if you use it.